# Covariant vs partial derivatives in polar coordinate system

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

Covariant derivatives take into account for both component and basis changes, thereby applicable for curved spaces - where partial derivatives only take component changes into account - is this statement correct? In a polar coordinate system basis changes, even though the space is flat. Will that be considered in partial derivatives? Or we need covariant derivative for that?